# How to Print on JTextArea

Tags: java

I'm learning to program in Java and I'm creating my first GUI App. It about creating 100 random numbers. I did it first on cmd like this:

```
public class RandomNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args){

        float n = 100;
        float m = 1513;
        float a = 19713;
        float x = 177963;
        float c = 1397;
        float r;
        float i;

        for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
            r = (a*x+c)%m;
            x = r;
            r = r/m;

            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason when i try to print the 100 random numbers on a text area, it only prints me one.This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class GUIRandomNumbers extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        public JTextArea area;
    public JScrollPane scroll;
    public JButton button;

    public RandomNumbers(){
        setLayout(null);
        area = new JTextArea();
        area.setEditable(false);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
        scroll.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 300);
        add(scroll);

        button = new JButton("Generate");
        button.setBounds(10, 650, 100, 25);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        float n = 100;
        float m = 1513;
        float a = 19713;
        float x = 177963;
        float c = 1397;
        float r;
        float i;
        if(e.getSource()==button){
            for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
                r = (a*x+c)%m;
                x = r;
                r = r/m;

                area.setText(String.valueOf(r));
            }

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        RandomNumbers p1 = new RandomNumbers();
        p1.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 750);
        p1.setVisible(true);

    }   

}
```

What could be the problem? I will really appreciae your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code doesnt even compile

Comment: String is not a text, text is a formatted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
area.append(String.valueOf(r) + "\n\r");
```

instead of

```
area.setText(String.valueOf(r));
```

Answer (score 5):

when you do

`area.setText(String.valueOf(r));`

it overwrites the text on the text area with the new text.

you should use

```
area.append(String);
```

method instead.

Answer (score 2):

`setText(String)` method replace the previous text. Use `area.append(String)` method.

Accordint to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)

Appends the given text to the end of the document. Does nothing if the model is null or the string is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

At first I suppose that you mean

```
 GUIRandomNumbers p1 = new GUIRandomNumbers();
```

The reason that makes you see only one number is that one number is written above the other.
I mean that you write 100 times a random number in the textArea!

`area.append("text");`
is the method that will do your job!